# Even if I write data-offset-bottom, Bootstrap Affix still fixes the nav bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Excuse me, but what's wrong with this code?
As you can see [here](http://bananaman.herokuapp.com/affix/), `Bootstrap Affix` still traces even though I write `data-offset-bottom`.
I read several pages and copied and pasted, it didn't work well. 
Would you please help me?

```js
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var ScrTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#intervalValue').val(ScrTop);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
   color: red;
  }
  .container-fluid {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .row {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*.affix-bottom {
    position: absolute;
  }*/
  .affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
  div#interval {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="interval">current scroll value: <input type="text" size="10" value="0" id="intervalValue"></div>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
    <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
    <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll</h3>
    <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
    <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</p>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197" data-offset-bottom="50">  <!-- Affix start when scrolling quantity is 197 and end at 100 from bottom -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic Topnav</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="height:1000px">
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: You want to fix the navbar or not and if yes where at the top or bottom.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your comment. I want to make it like [this site](http://bootstrap3.cyberlab.info/javascript/affix-bottom.html).

Comment: If you don't want affix remove data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197" data-offset-bottom="50" from your navbar.

Comment: To understand how affix exactly work you can checkout some pretty good example here - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-affix.php